# Sphinx doesn't find Python packages when using autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I'm trying to create documentation for test Python project before doing it for the real project. 
My system : Win7 64 bit, python 2.7.5 64 bit.

My project name is **testDoc**. It includes python pakage, named **t**, which includes 2 modules **t1** and **t2** and `__init__.py`.

`__init__.py` contains:

```
import t1
import t2
```

t1.py contains:

```
'''
Created on 27  2013

@author: 
'''

class MyClass(object):
    '''
    Hi
    '''


    def __init__(self,selfparams):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        pass
```

To create docs I run in the command line in **testDoc**:

```
sphinx-apidoc -A "me" -F -o docs .
```

Sphinx creates many files and it's ok according to Sphinx docs. 
Then, **conf.py** is modified

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(absolute path to testDoc))
```

I enter **docs** folder and type

```
make html
```

and get the following erroneous output:

```
Making output directory...
Running Sphinx v1.1.3
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 50%] index
reading sources... [100%] t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 321, in impor
t_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named t.__init__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 321, in impor
t_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named t.t1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 321, in impor
t_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named t.t2

...testDoc\t\docs\t.rst:7: WARNING: a
autodoc can't import/find module 't.__init__', it reported error: "No module name
d t.__init__", please check your spelling and sys.path
...testDoc\t\docs\t.rst:15: WARNING:
autodoc can't import/find module 't.t1', it reported error: "No module named t.t
1", please check your spelling and sys.path
t...testDoc\t\docs\t.rst:23: WARNING:
autodoc can't import/find module 't.t2', it reported error: "No module named t.t
2", please check your spelling and sys.path
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 50%] index
writing output... [100%] t

writing additional files... (0 module code pages) genindex search
copying static files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 3 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know what the "absolute path to testDoc" is, but from the Sphinx output I can see that the `testDoc` directory structure is `testDoc/t/docs`. The `docs` directory is where `conf.py` is.

For the module search path to be set up properly, you need to go two levels up from `conf.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../.."))
```