# How to build the cython doc on readthedoc and in local

Tags: python, cython, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am currently working on a cython project.

After following some tutorials, I was able to `build in place` cython, then use sphinx build with the line

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../')) # path to my_package` in my conf.py to make it work.

Unfortunately, I need to delete this line to make it work with readthedocs as suggested here: [how to document cython function on readthedocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238736/how-to-document-cython-function-on-readthedocs).

My question is, what is the best practice to build documentation on read the docs and locally with the same code?

read-the-docs creates a venv, pip install requirements, install the cython project and then run `sphinx-build`.

I would like to avoid doing the same locally because this is time consuming. Is there antoher way? Which one is the best practice?

Comment: Always create and use a virtual environment. `venv` is a tool in Python 3 that creates a virtual environment, so one does not "create a venv". Install packages and your project into the virtual environment. Now beyond that, you will get many differing opinions. I would recommend that you find a project that is documented on RTD and that includes documentation for how to build the project's docs locally as well, like almost any project under the Pylons Project, like [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/HACKING.txt#L116-L123), which uses `tox` to run tests and build docs.

Comment: @StevePiercy, thank you I am going to check (Actually I would like to avoid creating a virtual env, it is time consuming), but I will check the different projects, thank you very much

Comment: What exactly is time consuming about creating a virtual environment? It's one step: `python3 -m venv env`. It is definitely faster to destroy your system with `sudo pip install many_conflicting_packages` than using a virtual environment, so I'll give you that point.

Comment: You are right, I do not have many packages. I will test it out and tell you more once it is done ! :)

Comment: There are lots of ways to install many packages, and I won't go into them all, but `pip install p1 p2 p3 ...` works just fine.

Comment: @StevePiercy, if you write an answer, I will accept it. Doing some venv is not that time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always create and use a virtual environment. `venv` is a tool in Python 3 that creates a virtual environment, so one does not "create a venv". Install packages and your project into the virtual environment.

```
# create and change working directory
mkdir ~/projects/myproject
cd ~/projects/myproject
# create a virtual environment for your project
python3 -m venv env
# activate the virtual environment
source env/bin/activate
# optionally upgrade packaging tools
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
# install your package in editable mode into your virtual environment
pip install -e .
# install other packages into your virtual environment
pip install sphinx another_package one_more_package
```

Now do all your Sphinx stuff and follow the rest of the instructions at the link you provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks ! As a side note, I might be using venv wrong, but for me venv is a shortcut for virtual env, isnt it?

Comment: No. These are all different terms with unique definitions and usage. See the Python 3 module [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), the tool [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), and term [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-virtual-environment). "virtual env" with a space is nonsense even though it sounds like the tool.